# Prevent flex item from shrinking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### Sample:

```css
#wrap {
  outline: 1px solid fuchsia;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background: tan;
  width: 100%;
}

#right {
  background: teal;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

### Screenshot:

[image]

### Questions:

1. When I use the browser element inspector, I see the right box is less than `50px` wide although it has a fixed width in the CSS. Why does it basically happen?
2. How can it be prevented?

Comment: See ***The `flex-shrink` factor*** section in the duplicate for an explanation.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use **flex-shrink: 0;** on the #right element to prevent it from shrinking.

This just defines that the #right element should not be allowed to shrink e.g. stays at 50px.

For more informations about flex there are many good articles e.g. on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex: 1 1;` on `#left` instead of `width:100%`

```css
#wrap {
  outline: 1px solid fuchsia;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background: tan;
  flex: 1 1;
}

#right {
  background: teal;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

> *flex: `<positive-number>`*
>
> Equivalent to flex:  1 0.
>   Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.

**[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)**

Comment: What if I don't use the `flex` property? Can I still have a `50px` × `50px` box while using `width:100%`?

Comment: @Mike The proper use of `flexbox` would be to set `flex: 1` on the `left` element. If to keep the `width: 100%`, set `flex-shrink: 0` on the `right`, as _Stefan F._ suggested in his answer.